# Why would SSH ask for password every other day?

Tags: permissions, ssh

So I've been using ssh for quite a while with a server for the company I work with. Since about a month ago ssh keeps asking me for my passphrase for the rsa key, mind you, it does it every other day. One day it doesn't ask for it and the next day it does, and the cycle repeats every other day.

I've set my `id_rsa.pub` key to `-rw-r--r--` and my private key to `-rw------`

What could be the cause of this?

#### EDIT 1:

It's my own computer, I'm the only user, I'm a freelance webdev. I've Been using ssh flawlessly for a few years now, and the issue started a month ago.

Comment: Look for problems with *seahorse*, the key manager of Ubuntu.

Comment: It's my own computer, I'm a freelance webdev. Been using ssh flawlessly for a few years now, and the issue started a month ago.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.